# Download JSP taglibs (spring form, spring security, jstl core , jstl fmt ) in spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl, jsp-tags

I would like to know if there's a way to download the **taglibs** such as spring form, spring security, jstl core , jstl fmt, and use them directly within my app, without declaring them using the direct link to the page in URI like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: because the client might not have internet connection

Comment: Whose is the client we are talking about? JSP rendering happens at server side. Remember its just a uri. It does not download anything on every client browser.

Comment: I'm talking about the actual client who's going to use the app haha ! if i understand correctly, it won't download anything using that link, it's only a link to the actual class in the jar i'm using ?

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

taglib URI is not an URL which you can connect. All the taglibs are classes, not web pages. If you want to use the JSTL taglib's you have to download the jstl.jar. Extract the jar and you will see the classes with the same package structure like /jsp/jstl/core. check out this to know how to create custom taglibs [tutorial.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm)

Comment: I did just what you told me and from what I understand, uri is just a link to the class that's going to be used, in the actual jar